# Error: Class 'App\Models\AProduct' not found

Tags: php, json, laravel, postman

For my Laravel assignment I am using models to create add products. However, the postman gives me the error of class not found. I am a bit stumped on that to be honest. Here is the AProductController I use:

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use App\Models\AProduct;
 class AProductController extends Controller
 {
  //
  function addAProduct(Request $req)
  {
    $aProduct=new AProduct;
    $aProduct->name=$req->input('name');
    $aProduct->price=$req->input('price');
    $aProduct->color=$req->input('color');
    $aProduct->file_path=$req->file('file')->store('aproducts');
    $aProduct->save();
    return $aProduct;
  }
}
```

AProduct Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AProduct extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

I am getting this error in postman

```
Error: Class 'App\Models\AProduct' not found in file D:\Savindi\University\4th year\Project\Our 
Project\Project\ecomm-backend\app\Http\Controllers\AProductController.php on line 12
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 4):

On **AProduct Model**, change your namespace :

```
namespace App;
```

to

```
namespace App\Models;
```